# Top navbar collapse not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a bootstrap based website with vertical menu which can be toggled with a button and top bar which collapsible when screen size reduces. I managed to add a log out link but when the screen size reduces the log out doesn't appear in top navbar collapse menu. I am not sure where I am going wrong

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>staff_admin</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default no-margin">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header fixed-brand">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"  id="menu-toggle">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                      <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>


                </div><!-- navbar-header-->

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="active" ><button class="navbar-toggle collapse in" data-toggle="collapse" id="menu-toggle-2"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
            </ul>

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul></div>
                </div><!-- bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 -->
    </nav>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="menu">

                <li class="active">
                    <a href="admission_dec.html" target="admission"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Dashboard</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Administration</a>
                       <ul class="nav-pills nav-stacked" style="list-style-type:none;">
                        <li><a href="admission_tte.html" target="admission">Enrol</a></li>
                        <li><a href="usermgmt.html" target="admission">SysAdmin</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Student Management</a>
                    <ul class="nav-pills nav-stacked" style="list-style-type:none;">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Assessment</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Vehicle Management</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"> <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-stack-1x "></i></span>About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-server fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid xyz">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" >
     <iframe name="admission" class="embed-responsive-item" style="margin-left:0px; background-color: white;max-height:1500px" ></iframe>  
     </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sidebar_menu.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
     $("#menu-toggle-2").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled-2");
        $('#menu ul').hide();
    });

     function initMenu() {
      $('#menu ul').hide();
      $('#menu ul').children('.current').parent().show();
      //$('#menu ul:first').show();
      $('#menu li a').click(
        function() {
          var checkElement = $(this).next();
          if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            return false;
            }
          if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
            checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            return false;
            }
          }
        );
      }
    $(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});




 #wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 235px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    padding: -20px;
    width: 100%;  
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
.xyz{
    min-width: 360px;
}
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0px; 
}
.fixed-brand{
    width: auto;
}
/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    border-left: red 2px solid;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}
.no-margin{
    margin:0;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }
    .fixed-brand{
        width: 250px;
    }
    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }
    #wrapper.toggled-2 #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 50px;
    }
    #wrapper.toggled-2 #sidebar-wrapper:hover {
        width: 250px;
    }


    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: -20px;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
        padding-left: 250px;
    }
    #wrapper.toggled-2 #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: -200px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        width: auto;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is working fine for me *[see fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/gdexp9qo/)*

Comment: no its not working, review again

Answer (score 1):

Replace your navbar `<nav>` code with this. It is working now. Tested in your fiddle.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default no-margin">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header fixed-brand">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" id="menu-toggle">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#text">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <!-- navbar-header-->

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="text">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active">
        <button class="navbar-toggle collapse in" data-toggle="collapse" id="menu-toggle-2"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
      </li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Lin</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 -->
</nav>
```